# Help prevent Back button from closing sub-activity

Tags: android, back-button

I have a main activity.  It's main purpose is to handle Tab menu.  If a user click a tab it'll load another activity as a sub-activity, still showing the tab menu. I am using Intent to do this:

```
setContent(new Intent(this,B.class))
```

This sub-activity has an onclick function as well. If the user clicks one of the links it'll load xml layout file using setContentView command:

```
setContentView(R.layout.B1);
```

Now, when the back button is pressed while xml file is loaded, it'll close the entire application.  Is there a way to prevent this, say, return to the sub-activity or the main activity?

thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should override the onBackPressed method in your activity or sub activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {       
    //TODO Do your task here
}
```

Comment: actually, to prevent the activity from closing you should not call to `super.onBackPressed()`

Comment: @igagis Thanks for pointing out mistake. Didn't seen it since 8 years :)

Answer (score 6):

In your sub activity you should override the fallowing:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {

       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  //Override Keyback to do nothing in this case.
       {
           return true;
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);  //-->All others key will work as usual
   }
```